# Redirect from plugin Magento 2

Tags: magento2, custom, plugin, magento2.2.3, redirect-url

I am trying to redirect to custom URL by using [plugin](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html) feature of Magento 2 but somehow I am not able to redirect it. For this, I tried a couple of options like,

> [Magento2: redirection from Observer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/112993/magento2-redirection-from-observer)
>
> [Magento2: Redirect Using Plugin (With Website Restrictions ON)](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/134993/magento2-redirect-using-plugin-with-website-restrictions-on)

But couldn't succeed with this. I am able to do it If I am adding `exit();` after redirect method but it is not good practice to write `exit();`. Do anyone have some hint on this?

I am using `around` plugin and before `plugin`

I have written a plugin on `Magento\Customer\Model\AccountManagement` class.

Thanks

Comment: ON which class you have tried  to plugin

Comment: see my edit @AmitBera

Comment: See the blog  of Fabian Schmengler https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/220195/best-way-to-replace-the-die-function/220529#220529...

Comment: also, you can idea from https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/226495/4564 alternative solution.

Comment: ON which method  you have trying?

Comment: Thanks for the info I tried them but couldn't help me in my case. @AmitBera

Comment: I am trying on `initiatePasswordReset()` @AmitBera

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77683/discussion-between-amit-bera-and-keyur-shah).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**As per as, our discussion, I am sharing an idea that might help you.**

- First, pass a registry variable from initiatePasswordReset that
  registry variable will contain your desired URL.
- Then at
  `controller_action_postdispatch_customer_account_forgotPasswordPost`event
  catch that  registry variable value, that page

Create Plugin over `initiatePasswordReset` call and use **after, before ,around method depend on your choose.**

Here, i am using around method.

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by Amit Bera.
 * User: Amit Kumar Bera
 * Email: dev.amitbera@gmail.com
 * Date: 19-05-2018
 * Time: 17:03
 */

namespace StackExchange\Works\Plugin;


use Magento\Framework\Registry;

class InitiatePasswordResetPlugin
{
    protected $registry;
    public function __construct(
        Registry $registry
    )
    {
        $this->registry = $registry;
    }
    public function aroundInitiatePasswordReset(
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $subject,
        \Closure $proceed,
        $email,
        $template,
        $websiteId
    )
    {
        // Do business logic here
        if($this->registry->registry('my_custom_redirect')){
            $this->registry->unregister('my_custom_redirect');
        }
        $this->registry->register('my_custom_redirect','{YourUrl}');
        return $proceed($email, $template, $websiteId);

    }

}
```

Now, `controller_action_postdispatch_customer_account_forgotPasswordPost` event,

redirect that URL `my_custom_redirect`.

```
<?php

namespace StackExchange\Works\Observer\Frontend;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;

class ControllerActionPostdispatchForgotPasswordPost implements ObserverInterface
{

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\ActionFlag
     */
    protected $actionFlag;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\ActionFlag $actionFlag,
         Registry $registry
    ) {
         $this->registry = $registry;
        $this->actionFlag        = $actionFlag;
    }

    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {

        $action = $observer->getEvent()->getControllerAction();

        if($this->registry->registry('my_custom_redirect')){
            $this->actionFlag->set('', \Magento\Framework\App\ActionInterface::FLAG_NO_DISPATCH, true);
            $action->getResponse()->setRedirect($this->registry->registry('my_custom_redirect'));
            return $this;
        }
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Amit for your efforts ! +1 from me , but do you know direct forcefully redirect without writing extra observer?   Like in observer we can forcefully redirect by setting 'FLAG_NO_DISPATCH` but in plugin?

Comment: `FLAG_NO_DISPATCH` cannot used to observer, if  your does have any controller object at your observer

Comment: I think we can use `FLAG_NO_DISPATCH`  in observer please check https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/app/code/Magento/Captcha/Observer/CheckForgotpasswordObserver.php#L73 @Amit

Comment: you can use `FLAG_NO_DISPATCH`   this observer  have controller object https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/app/code/Magento/Captcha/etc/events.xml#L15-L17

Comment: Yes, with the use of controller object we can use it @Amit

Comment: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Action/Action.php#L98-L101

Comment: then  if you will  use predispatch then `execute` method will not work

Answer (score 5):

Below is a working example from my own code. It only requires 2 files.

Create **di.xml** file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Backend\App\AbstractAction">
        <plugin name="Vendorname\Modulename\Plugin\Backend\App\AbstractAction" type="Vendorname\Modulename\Plugin\Backend\App\AbstractAction" />
    </type>
</config>
```

Create the plugin file

```
<?php

namespace Vendorname\Modulename\Plugin\Backend\App;

class AbstractAction
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory
     */
    private $resultFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Response\RedirectInterface
     */
    private $redirect;

    /**
     * AbstractAction constructor.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory       $resultFactory
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Response\RedirectInterface $redirect
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory $resultFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Response\RedirectInterface $redirect
    ) {
        $this->resultFactory        = $resultFactory;
        $this->redirect             = $redirect;
    }

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Backend\App\AbstractAction     $subject
     * @param \Closure                                $procede
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface|\Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface|\Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Json
     */
    public function aroundDispatch($subject, $procede, $request)
    {
        if ($yourCondition) {
            $resultRedirect = $this->resultFactory->create(
                \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT
            );

            // if you want to redirect to the previous page
            $result = $resultRedirect->setUrl($this->redirect->getRefererUrl());

            // if you want to redirect to an external url
            $result = $resultRedirect->setUrl('https://www.google.com');
        } else {
            $result = $procede($request);
        }

        return $result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I can use this in Dispatch but what If I want to use in some custom methods?

Comment: What is the condition going to be? I can help you figure out the best time/place to check it and do the redirect.

Comment: Yes, sure, I am using `around ` plugin in `Magento\Customer\Model\AccountManagement` on `initiatePasswordReset()` method @Shawn

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to achieve here, but if you limit your problem to redirecting to a different url from a plugin, I can give you some ideas.
Since the `Magento\Customer\Api\AccountManagementInterface` does not act as a controller maybe you should not try to redirect from one of the methods from the implementation of this interface.
only controllers should handle the request and send the response.
The method `initiatePasswordReset` is called from 2 controller actions `Magento\Customer\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\ResetPassword::execute` and `Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\ForgotPasswordPost::execute`.
Maybe you should pluginize these methods using `after` or `around`.
Both methods above return an instance of `\Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Redirect` so it is pretty easy to change the return value of them via a plugin. (I suggest `after`, but you may need `around`, not sure of your requirements).

an after plugin could look like this (but you already know that):

```
public function afterExecute(
     \Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\ResetPassword $subject, $redirect, 
     \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Redirect $redirect
) {
     //custom logic in here;
     if (your condition) {
          $redirect->setPath('custom/action/page');
     }
     return $redirect;
}
```

If you have a lot of custom logic, in order to avoid content duplication you can move the logic to a custom class and use that class as a dependency in both plugins you are creating.

Comment: I am agree with  you!  Not possible  direction from `AccountManagement`

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) I am using `around` plugin because I have some custom logic and on based on custom logic I need to forcefully redirect to another URL. Yes, I can use `after` plugin to change URL but It will not fulfill my all requirenment.

Comment: Maybe you should explain in the question what are you trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code and replace `setUrl` with `setPath`

```
$result = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
$result->setPath('path/to/controller'); //ex. 'customer/account/login'
return $result;
```

Comment: Please don't post multiple answers, please answer in an answer .You can edit your post yourself

Answer (score -1):

Inject 2 classes in Constructor like below:

```
public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $url, Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory $resultFactory)
{
    $this->resultFactory = $resultFactory;           
    $this->url = $url;
}
```

Code to redirect :

```
$result = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
$result->setUrl($this->url->getUrl('path/to/controller'));
return $result;
```

Comment: Did you try this answer in `plugin` class? I know I can use this on `controller` but not in `plugin`

Comment: Yes. Please try it and up vote if it works for you.

Comment: Is it working ?

Comment: unfortunately no  :)